# UI Widget blueprints not activated when packaging the game (shipping)

Tags: unreal-engine5, unreal-umg

I’m kinda new to Unreal although I’ve had some months of intensive usage. I have an issue that is stopping me to continue developing my game. For some reason, the code I have (BP) works okay on PIE & Standalone but the functions aren’t activated when packaging. I have noticed that this usually happens more when using shipping binary configuration.

In this particular case, I’m trying to call a function that plays an animation that’s inside the Widget (WB_Main). The widget is initialized correctly and it just displays a crosshair in the middle of the screen, the widget also contains a hidden text that is animated when the character through a line trace interacts with an actor. As I mentioned, it works as intended but when packaging, the animation is never called.

I checked the output and there are no major or relevant errors. After two weeks I don’t have any clue about why this is happening.

[This is how I call the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5eAp.png)

[This is the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0zBs.png)

[This is how I call the widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N097Z.png)

I tried to make widgets to be called in the packaged version. It works in editor and Standalone, but not when I try to package the game in shipping configuration.